# Encrypted partition reports wrong size

Tags: partition, disk-usage, luks

I have partitioned my 1TB drive with a luks encrypted partition. The `fdisk -l` output is

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 953,89 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk model: INTEL SSDPEKNW010T8
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D7D712F4-077A-47DD-93AA-DB024B082A7A

Device              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048    1050623    1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    1050624    2549759    1499136   732M Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3    2549760 1767190527 1764640768 841,5G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p4 1767190528 1769287679    2097152     1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p5 1769287680 1865764863   96477184    46G Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/nvme0n1p3_crypt: 841,46 GiB, 903493976064 bytes, 1764636672 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 840,38 GiB, 902337396736 bytes, 1762377728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 1 GiB, 1073741824 bytes, 2097152 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

The main partition is about 840GB, but `df -Th /` shows:

```
Filesystem                  Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ext4   98G   97G  903M 100% /
```

The size is shown as only 98GB! As you see I'm close to having that partition full by `df`'s reckoning and I often get messages that the disk is almost full, however the partition is actually much larger. Why is that?

**Update**

To give some context this was the result of partitioning during the installation of Ubuntu on my Intel NUC. I had lots of problems with the booting of the system and spent hours trying to fix the encrypted partition. So I probably messed up something.

`lvdisplay /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root` shows

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg
  LV UUID  bX0P8g-LX6v-M9YK-0Lon-Uw3C-xQcl-SLYjWX
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2019-08-30 10:49:40 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size  <840,37 GiB
  Current LE             215134
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:4
```

`pvs`:

```
  PV                          VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree 
  /dev/mapper/nvme0n1p3_crypt ubuntu-vg lvm2 u--  841,44g 76,00m
```

`lvs`:

```
  LV     VG        Attr       LSize    Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root   ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- <840,37g                                                    
  swap_1 ubuntu-vg -wi-ao----    1,00g
```

Comment: Can you show the output of: `lvdisplay /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root` as well?

Comment: Your partitioning scheme is really not good at all. Also having 100GB for the root is usually more than enough. You can reserve the rest of your space for /var /home /srv etc.

Comment: To be honest I was surprised that the Ubuntu installer by default proposed to have just one big partition for the drive (plus boot and swap partitions). I figured that it didn't matter that much and mostly followed the default. But I've kept about 100GB to have one or more partitions (without encryption) to be able to install another OS and boot into that. Currently I have a Centos partition there (/dev/nvme0n1p5), which I've excluded from the output from most of the commands here since I didn't think was relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your large disk partition `/dev/nvme0n1p3` appears to contain a LUKS encrypted container `/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p3_crypt`.

At a guess this in turn contains a Volume Group called `ubuntu-vg`, and you can confirm this with `pvs`. The reason for this guess is that you have shown us two Logical Volumes, named `root` and `swap` belonging to a VG called `ubuntu-vg`.

What's strange is that the root LV is around 840 GiB, but it only contains a filesystem of around 98GB.

Usually, there's little point creating an LV that's so much larger than the filesystem it contains, and my recommendation would be to reduce it down to 120 GB or so. This will allow you to grow it again as necessary or even to create a new LV should you need one.

You don't need to shrink the LV but here are the steps to do so. In general, DO NOT SHRINK A LOGICAL VOLUME unless the filesystem it contains is already small enough to fit the target size. Get this wrong and you'll destroy your filesystem.

**Take a backup of your files before you try this. Borrow a disk if you have to, but take a backup. Really.**

In your case the filesystem is only 98GB so we can safely reduce the LV to 120GB. (This easily allows for misconversions between GB and GiB.) At the same time we increase the filesystem size to match.

```
lvresize --size 120G --resizefs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
```

Thereafter you can increase the filesystem size incrementally, for example to 200GB

```
lvresize --size 200G --resizefs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
```

If you really don't want to change the size of the 840GB root LV container you can simply and safely resize the filesystem within it. This increases its size to 120GB

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 120GB
```

Omit the size to have the filesystem completely fill the LV (all 840GB of it). I don't recommend this, though.

Comment: I don't want to shrink the logical volume, I want to use all or most of it for my filesystem. I've run `resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 120GB` but got: `resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
resize2fs: Invalid new size: 120GB`

Comment: Please add `pvs` , `lvs`, and `df -h /` to your question

Comment: I've added that now

Comment: My apologies, I meant `df -Th /`, please, not just `df -h /`. I need to see the filesystem type for `/`

Comment: I've added that now as well.